# Compile code using JavaFX 2.0 (using command line)

Tags: java, compilation, javafx-2

I wonder how to compile code using JavaFX, from a Windows shell.

I have this code in `fxservidor.java`:

```
public class Fxservidor extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Synthetizer os = new Synthetizer("Ximena");                
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

*Oracle Java 8*

If you are using Oracle Java 8 or newer, as pointed out by cayhorstmann in his answer, JavaFX classes are now on the default runtime classpath for an Oracle Java implementation.  You can just run `javac` and `java` on your program and the JavaFX classes will be found as expected, just like any other class in the JRE.

```
javac Fxservidor.java
java Fxservidor
```

*OpenJDK 8*

If you are using OpenJDK 8, you will (currently) need to [build the JavaFX sources](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) from the OpenJFX repository and and place the resultant jfxrt.jar on your classpath similar to the description for Java 7 defined in this answer.

*JavaFX 2.x / Java 7*

You use the [Java Compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) to compile JavaFX programs:

```
"%JDK_HOME%\bin\javac" -classpath "%JAVAFX_SDK_HOME%\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar" fxservidor.java
```

Replace the JDK_HOME and JAVAFX_SDK_HOME placeholders with the paths to your installed JDK and JavaFX SDK respectively.

A sample windows batch script for JavaFX 2.x command line development and deployment packaging is provided [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10005793).

Here is a command I ran on my machine to compile your application (you need to adjust the classpath for your environment):

```
javac -classpath "\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime\lib\jfxrt.jar" Fxservidor.java
```

And here is a command I used to run the compiled class:

```
java -classpath "\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime\lib\jfxrt.jar;." Fxservidor
```

Note the `;.` tokens used to append the current directory to the classpath of the java execution command in Windows (if using a Unix variant, then use `:.` instead of `;.`).

*Sample App*

Here is a modified version of your program which will compile:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Fxservidor extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

*Deployment Recommendation*

If you are deploying applications to users, even with Java 8, it is recommended that you package applications using relevant packaging tools (e.g. [JavaFX ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm), [javafxpackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafxpackager001.htm), [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) or [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle)).

If you just want to do some quick command line development and testing, of small programs, those additional packaging tools are not needed and you can just use the simple steps in this answer.

Comment: Error:Can't find symbol Application

Comment: I updated the answer to include the missing import statements from your sample code, comment out the unsupplied Synthetizer class so the code can compile and add the exact command I used to compile and run the updated program.

Comment: In the case of OpenJDK on Ubuntu/Debian, you don't need to build from sources, but just install the openjfx package:

    `sudo apt-get install openjfx`

Answer (score 8):

In macbook, osx, etc, you can compile:

```
javac -cp "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar" Fxservidor.java
```

and run:

```
java -cp ".:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar" Fxservidor
```

Note the `.:` instead of  `.;`

Answer (score 5):

```
javac -classpath "\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime\lib\jfxrt.jar" Fxservidor.java
```

I ran the above command on Ubuntu Linux with `JavaFX2.0 beta` it compiled it's class files but when I tried to run it with this command it did not work.

```
java -classpath "\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 Runtime\lib\jfxrt.jar" Fxservidor
```

This is the error message I get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Fxservidor

Comment: I updated my answer: under Linux you need to append `:.` to the runtime classpath to allow the java runtime to find the classes you have compiled to the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, in JDK 8, the JavaFX jar seems to be available without having to put it on the classpath.

```
path/to/jdk1.8.0-b96/bin/javac HelloWorld.java
path/to/jdk1.8.0-b96/bin/java HelloWorld
```

works like you'd expect.

Comment: Yep, my answer was dated - I updated it to include the new information.

Answer (score 2):

Raw but simple solution is to put a copy of jfxrt.jar file into the
  **.../jre7/lib/ext**
directory under your java installation.

Then, you should always have it available on your classpath.

Not recommended for distributing jfx apps, of course, but convenient for developer playing around...

(For explanation, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)