# JavaFX: is the fxml module ported to java 7 from JavaFX 8?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am using the JavaFX included in Java7u67. I have been trying to find the source code for `FXMLLoader` [**here**](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2.2/master/rt/) but it isn't there. However, in the [JavaFX 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/6ba670dbf9a4/modules) source base there is a module called `fxml`. Which `fxml` is included in the Java7u67? Oacle says that  Java7u67 includes JavaFX `2.2.67` but I cannot find that version of JavaFX.

Answer (score 2):

*Nothing is back ported from JavaFX 8 into JavaFX 2*. It is also true for all versions of Java. All later versions have added functionality on the previous version (though some unwanted functionality may also be removed)

The most probable reason you can't find fxml in source of JavaFX 2 is because

> **JavaFX 2 is partially open-sourced**

whereas

> **JavaFX 8 is completely open-sourced**

FXML is present and will work in Oracle Java 7 as long as you have the [runtime classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888367/compiling-and-running-with-javafx-2-1) for your application set up correctly.