# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TrackPlayer.MainTrack

Tags: java, fxml

I keep getting this error when I try to run my main class file...I can't understand where the error lies, still relatively new to coding :/

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain TrackPlayer.MainTrack
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TrackPlayer.MainTrack
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

This is the code for the main class:

```
package TrackPlayer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainTrack extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    initRootLayout();
    showThemer();
}

private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainTrack.class.getResource("TrackPlayer/rootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = /*(BorderPane)*/ loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void showThemer() {
    try {
        // Load person overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainTrack.class.getResource("TrackPlayer/Themer.fxml"));
        SplitPane Themer = /*(SplitPane)*/ loader.load();

        rootLayout.setCenter(Themer);

        /* Give the controller access to the main app.
        ThemerController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainTrack(this); */

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I can't figure out how to correct it, would anyone know what's wrong with the code? 
Thank you!

Comment: How are you launching the program? What is your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem I used idea and in my PC were difference version of java. I selected file->project structure and in modules and SDKs set same java version and this helped to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run a javafx application.
The link [compiling-and-running-with-javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888367/compiling-and-running-with-javafx-2-1) will help you to compile and run your javafx application.