# I have an error when deploying .jar generated with Maven with jfx import

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I generated a "package" .jar with dependancies using maven, however when deployed, developer who deployed it have the following error :

```
10:23:27.604 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> company.Api.convertXmlToPdf(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/util/Pair
10:23:27.606 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> company.Api.convertXmlToPdf(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/util/Pair
10:23:27.606 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> company.Api.convertXmlToPdf(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/util/Pair
```

Seems like the .jar does not include any dependance with javafx/util/Pair.

I've tried to add the dependancies using maven, adding the lib to the project :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Does not work.

I've tried to add

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>hermes.Api</mainClass>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

in my build configuration (pom). Does not work either...

When tested in local, it runs well all tests are passed and I've a result. When building the package lifecycle build with maven, the Build is successful. However, when deployed, I've the error mentionned above, like the `Pair` class is not found...

Both the developer machine and deployement machine are using

java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

(deployement machine is using _172 version...)

EDIT: it is not a solution to the issue, but since the only part of the javafx used in the code is Pair, I've repalced it by  [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) which is mostly the same as Pair. I hope this might help someone...

Comment: Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868446/javafx-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-applica

Comment: @Cromm Looks like it is jdk/jre versions nightmare. javafx.util.* is  not included in OpenJDK which is supposed to be used on deployement machine. If you use only Pair class from javafx.util.* just try to find alternative implementation of Pair i.e.Apache Commons library.

Comment: @Oleksandr : Thanks, yes, it was most likely a versionning issue, as stated in the last edit of my question, I implemented an alternative and changed Pair to SimpleEntry.