# How to import javafx in VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: java, visual-studio, javafx, visual-studio-code

I've tried to search everywhere to find a solution for this problem but no solution is present on the internet, it seems.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and visual studio code, while everything else seems to work, I'm not able to use the import statement. It gives error, stating "javafx could not be resolved".

[image]

I've installed javafx on my system but it is not available for use in VS code

[image]

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Add the jars your classpath.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Does [JavaFX-11 with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54349894/6395627) help?

Comment: Please don't post question-related information, or ask a new question, in the answer section. You should either [edit] your question (if you're providing more/clarifying information) or [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (if you have an entirely different question).

Comment: The solution given on this page worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868446/javafx-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-applica

Answer (score 0):

In your `.classpath` file, all you have to do is add entries for all the JavaFX jar files you want to load (probably all). Just be wary of moving the jar files as the error will then return. Then you should see the JavaFX libraries under your classpath and the compiler will then be able to resolve it.

Comment: I installed Eclipse 2019 and tried to add jars under Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE > Edit > Add External Jars  and added all the required jars. The problem of not able to resolve the class is gone but somehow now I get the error of "NoClassDefFound". What can I do about that?

Comment: @MohitTomar I'm not sure why you installed Eclipse if you're trying to use VS Code. Or have you decided to switch IDEs?

Comment: @Slaw: Actually it seemed that vsCode was too hard to deal with as most of the settings were only possible through copy and pasting codes from online forums like stackOverflow. I'm new to programming and wanted something easy and intuitive. Moreover I see that eclipse is widely used and a lot of help is available for eclipse so I decided to change from vsCode to Eclipse and will stick to it.

Comment: Also I'm able to find the solution to the problem. I've shared the solution below.