# I'm encounter a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and I don't know why it's occuring

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to write my first JavaFX program. This is the exact error line:
Error: Could not find or load main class me.GamingCuber.CPSTest.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
However, I don't know how this error is occuring. Here is the code down below:

```
package me.GamingCuber.CPSTest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    Button button;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception{
        
        primarystage.setTitle("Test your CPS!");
        button = new Button("Click here for CPS");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primarystage.setScene(scene);
        primarystage.show();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: maybe you can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868446/javafx-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-applica

Comment: How would I do this in eclipse? Thank you for responding

Comment: Ok, I think I can figure it out now. Thanks guys!

Comment: I tried providing a small tutorial in my answer.

Comment: HINT: When you encounter an unexplained exception, Google search the exception name.  It is guaranteed that ***lots*** of other people have encountered the same situation, and you can usually find a solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding arguments:

compile

```
javac --module-path /path/to/java-fx-libs/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml *.java
```

run

```
java --module-path /path/to/java-fx-libs/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml MyMainClass
```

In eclipse I think you need to navigate to Menu: Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler