# NoClassDefFoundError : cannot find main class in jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar, noclassdeffounderror

After countless days of trying to find an answer to my question, I've decided to post it here. I've been developping a monitoring application for my company, and as I'm about to distribute it, the jar file seems not runnable. The exact error is :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring.app.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring.app.Main
```

The Main class contains the main method that runs the application. It works fine when being run, meaning there is no compile time error.

I am building this project using Gradle. Here is my build.gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
}

group 'net.nephty'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring'
    mainClass = 'net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring.app.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = "18.0.2"
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.media', 'javafx.swing', 'javafx.web']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.5.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }

    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")

    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.4.0'


}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes 'Start-Class': 'net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring.app.Main'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring.app.Main'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'net.nephty.connectwisemonitoring.app.Main'
        )
    }
}
```

Because of the error I've had, I've tried unpacking the jar to see if my code was in the right location. When unpacking the jar, I see that there is no net/nephty/... directory and cannot find my code anywhere.

The manifest is being build properly, as all the specified attributes end up in the file.

I've looked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868446/javafx-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-applica), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70489776/im-encounter-a-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-and-i-dont-know-why-its-occurin), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278063/how-do-i-create-an-executable-fat-jar-with-gradle-with-implementation-dependenci) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455197/gradle-fatjar-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) post, as well as many many more but none seemed to solve my issue.

I've tried making a new project and re-writing my build.gradle file but to no avail.

When I use `gradle jar`, the code ends up in the jar, which is what I want. Unfortunately, `gradle jar` doesn't include dependencies AFAIK.

If you'd like a minimal reproducible example, you can try creating a new project using gradle and use my build.gradle file as well as a basic main class located in the correct path. If you'd like to have the code sample, I've uploaded it [here](https://transfer.sh/O18qVk/ConnectwiseMonitoring.zip).

I feel like I'm really really close to solving this, but I can't find the source of the issue. My best guess would be that it stems from this part of the build.gradle file :

```
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
```

where the runtimeClasspath would be wrong but I can't find anything about this.

Specs :

```
------------------------------------------------------------         
Gradle 7.5                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------         
                                                                     
Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC                                
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103               
                                                                     
Kotlin:       1.6.21                                                 
Groovy:       3.0.10                                                 
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.4+11-LTS-179)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Thanks in advance for your time. Let me know if I missed some information I should share.

EDIT : I've tried changing the duplicate strategy but that didn't do anything.

Comment: You are only packaging the dependencies, but not the actual code/resources itself. Where did you get the code for the `uberJar` from? Why not use this plugin for creating a fat-jar https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow ?

Comment: I don't quite remember, it's something I tried out but forgot to remove. What do you mean by using this plugin ? The build.gradle jar task or something more ?

Comment: The shadow plugin deals with all the intricacies of creating a fat/uber jar, I'm suggesting to use it, instead of trying to create your own task for it.