# Ant script fails to detect the javafx classes when compiling

Tags: ant, compilation, javafx

I am using the Ant script to compile my source code. previously it was compiling perfectly . recently i added classes  which uses javafx specific classes .after this ant is not compiling and it fails to find the javafx classes . i am using jdk 7 update 23  as javafx is inculded in the jdk, i cannot figure out   why compilation fails ?.

below  is my ant script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <project name="client" basedir="." default="compile" >
  <description>Client</description>

  <property file="build.properties" />

  <path id="classpath">

    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.*"/>
  </path>

  <!-- Initialization -->
  <target name="init" description="Prepare needed directories.">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Cleanup -->
  <target name="clean" description="Remove all files created by the build/test process.">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compile application -->
  <target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac source="1.7" target="1.7" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="yes" includeantruntime="false"  fork="true" memorymaximumsize="1200m" >
      <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
  </target>

  <path id="lib.lib">
     <fileset dir="../lib">
         <include name="**/*"/>
     </fileset>
  </path>

  <pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" lib/">
      <path refid="lib.lib"/>
      <flattenmapper/>
  </pathconvert>  

  <!-- Java Archive -->
  <target name="jar"  depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/Client.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/${mf.classpath}"/>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>

      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Suggested Solution*

If you want to use ant with JavaFX, you should use Oracle's [JavaFX ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm).

The JavaFX runtime is included with Java 7 and the Oracle JavaFX ant tasks are aware of it's location, so when you use the Oracle ant tasks, builds of projects referencing JavaFX work.

*Why your current build fails*

Compilation fails for your script because the JavaFX runtime (jfxrt.jar) is not on the default class path for Java 7.

For Java 8 the JavaFX runtime is on the class path.

You can still use plain ant without the Oracle JavaFX ant tasks to build your application (just by ensuring jfxrt.jar is on the class path for your build step), however use of the Oracle tasks is recommended as they will also appropriately package your application for distribution.

---

See also: [Compile code using JavaFX 2.0 (using command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-javafx-2-0-manually)