# Why can't I use JavaFX in JCreator?

Tags: java, import, javafx, jcreator

I'm currently using JCreator 5.0 and JDK 1.7.0_51. I haven't had any issues when coding, and this time I decided to adventure myself in the realms of JavaFX, but it seems I can't reach any of its content. Here's the error I get when I press the "Build File" button:

```
H:\Tareas\Projects\Test\Test1.java:1: error: package javafx.stage does not exist
import javafx.stage.*;
^
1 error
```

So, my questions are:

- Is there something I'm doing wrong?
- Am I missing something?

I actually haven't coded anything yet, it just seems the import is not working. This is the code so far, by the way, irrelevant I guess:

```
import javafx.stage.*;
public class Test1 {
    public Test1() { }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

By the way, javafx.stage.* is not the only thing that gets me errors, in general, anything coming from javafx.* does the same :C, even "javafx.*" itself, I'm just using that as an example. Cheers!

**edit:**

I solved it now! and I did it thanks to **@MadProgrammer**, after reading [the thread he provided me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-javafx-2-0-manually)! Thanks very much =) it was so simple!

So what I found after reading the thread is that I needed to tell JCreator that such package existed, so I went through these steps in JCreator:

- went to "Configure" menu
- then 'Options"
- then selected "JDK Profiles" in the left menu
- then selected my "JDK version 1.7.0_51" profile
- then clicked the "Edit..." button
- then in the "Classes" tab clicked the "Add" button
- then selected "Add Archive"
- then went to my "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib" folder to select "jfxrt.jar"
- and finally opened it, click in "Ok", "Ok", et c. and volia! no more errors!

**Too long, didn't read**: added "jfxrt.jar" to my JDK Profile in JCreator Options =)

Thanks very much!

I will be posting this as an answer soon, I just have to wait a couple hours due to having not enough reputation points, cheers everyone!

Comment: Try taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-javafx-2-0-manually) answer to explain why you're having problems

Comment: @MadProgrammer hey! thanks a lot! really! I'll be posting that as an answer soon! It's working now! cheers, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to "Configure" menu
- then 'Options"
- then select "JDK Profiles" in the left menu
- then select your "JDK version 1.7.0_51" profile
- then click the "Edit..." button
- then in the "Classes" tab click the "Add" button
- then select "Add Archive"
- then go to your "C:\Program Files\Java\jdkX.X.X_X\jre\lib" folder to select "jfxrt.jar"
- and finally open it, click on "Ok", "Ok", et c. and done.

Too long, didn't read: add "jfxrt.jar" to your JDK Profile in JCreator Options =)