# JavaFX on Windows install not found

Tags: java, javafx

On Oracle's website it is mentioned that for the JavaFX API, JDK SE 7 is required as it comes with JDK 7 or higher.

I have already downloaded and installed JDK SE 7 but i'm having a problem.

When I write the following code

```
import javafx.*   
class A {  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        System.out.println("hi")  
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error "package javafx does not exist" Also in my JDK folder I couldn't see the package "javafx" as it is the case with other packages like "java" or "javax" There's no issue with path(till bin) and classpath(till lib), I have set it correctly as I'm able to compile and run other programs, how can I sort this out?

Comment: Did you add `jfxrt.jar` to your project? (this should be in your java bin)

Comment: possible duplicate of [compile javafx 2.0 manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-javafx-2-0-manually)

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: Hey! i'm not using any IDE ,i'm compiling it from cmd,now what should i do ? Please don't say that an IDE is necessary for javafx.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to successfully build your code by placing the `jfxrt.jar` into the project's build path.

This JAR is located where you installed your JDK, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar`.

To add this to your project's build path on Eclipse, right click your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Add External JARS...

Comment: Correct. Note that in Java 8, JavaFX will be included on the classpath by default, so you won't have to do anything when you use Java 8.

Comment: hey! i'm not using any IDE.i'm simply compiling it from cmd .now what i'v to do to compile it.

Comment: @user3367768 `javac -classpath <PATH TO jfxrt.jar> <YOUR CLASS>`