# Why Java desktop app needs special deploy when JavaFX is used?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have small Java **desktop** application without any GUI. I use **Ant** to dev, run, build and release it. I didn't create a jar file for it. I use a **.sh** file to launch/run it with the **attached JRE** in the release.

Now I added a simple **JavaFX** 2 GUI on top of it. I still can dev, run, build and release with Ant. There is no special target or addition in the Ant file for **JavaFX**. After release, I cannot run it with the existing .sh  file any more. I got the following error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application**

If I change to launch another entry point without **JavaFX** involved in the **.sh** file, it works.

I am pretty sure if I use Swing it will work right way. Why **JavaFX** is special? Do I have to use **Ant** or **javafxpackager** to do special deploy? Any simple way to resolve this? it is a desktop application only.

I am using jdk/jre 1.7.0_51 and on linux.

I am new to JavaFX. don't know if it is worthy to learn it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compile javafx 2.0 manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-javafx-2-0-manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using Java 7 or older, then the JavaFX runtime jar file is not in the classpath by default. You need to include it in the classpath.

Add the jar `jfxrt.jar` to the classpath; you can find it in the `jre\lib` directory of your Java installation.

This will change for Java 8; there, JavaFX will be in the classpath by default and you will not need to add the jar to the classpath yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the JRE you include with your app brings in its bundle the JavaFX version you need.  A recent version of the JRE should bring it without any problem as explained here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javafx/downloads/index.html