# What's the location of the JavaFX runtime JAR file, jfxrt.jar, on Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, javafx, java

I'm trying to run some JavaFX code with Eclipse Kepler, with [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/) plugin installed, on a Linux machine, using:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

My understanding is that although JavaFX has been included with the standard JDK since version JDK 7u6, the JavaFX runtime JAR file, jfxrt.jar, was left off of the Java runtime path on purpose until further testing between JavaFX and rest of the java infrastructure has been completed. For this reason you must manually add it to the project build path libraries when we create a new Java project.

I've been looking for that jar in both the following directories without success:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-common/jre/lib/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib
```

Where else should I look for it?

Comment: Try to run on shell `locate jfxrt.jar` to see da location

Comment: Mine is in jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib, but that's using the standard JDK, not OpenJDK.

Comment: You might also want to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk

Answer (score 65, accepted):

*Update March 2021*

The previous information in this answer is now obsolete for later versions of Java and JavaFX (e.g. Java 11+).  This update provides info for more recent versions.

JavaFX is now available from [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io) or the public Maven repository as an SDK or a library set, or a module set.  JavaFX has been partitioned into a set of dependencies rather than a monolithic `jfxrt.jar` library distributed with the Java runtime (as was previously the case with Oracle Java 8 for instance).

With versions 11+ of JavaFX, the location of the JavaFX jar files (and the native libraries to accompany them) will depend on how you build your project.  For example:

- If you use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle and specify JavaFX as a dependency, then the JavaFX jar files will be downloaded into your local Maven or Gradle repository (the same as other maven dependencies).
- If you download the JavaFX SDK from [openjfx.io (gluon)](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), then the JavaFX jar files will be in the location you unzipped the SDK to.

---

The location of jfxrt.jar in Oracle Java 7 is:

```
<JRE_HOME>/lib/jfxrt.jar
```

The location of jfxrt.jar in Oracle Java 8 is:

```
<JRE_HOME>/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

The `<JRE_HOME>` will depend on where you installed the Oracle Java and may differ between Linux distributions and installations.

jfxrt.jar is not in the Linux OpenJDK 7 (which is what you are using).

---

An open source package which provides [JavaFX 8 for Debian based systems](https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openjfx.html) such as Ubuntu is available.  To install this package it is necessary to install both the Debian OpenJDK 8 package and the Debian OpenJFX package.  I don't run Debian, so I'm not sure where the Debian OpenJFX package installs jfxrt.jar.

---

Use [Oracle Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

With Oracle Java 8, JavaFX is both included in the JDK and is on the default classpath.  This means that JavaFX classes will automatically be found both by the compiler during the build and by the runtime when your users use your application.  So using Oracle Java 8 is currently the best solution to your issue.

OpenJDK for Java 8 could include JavaFX (as JavaFX for Java 8 is now open source), but it will depend on the OpenJDK package assemblers as to whether they choose to include JavaFX 8 with their distributions.  I hope they do, as it should help remove the confusion you experienced in your question and it also provides a great deal more functionality in OpenJDK.

> My understanding is that although JavaFX has been included with the standard JDK since version JDK 7u6

Yes, but only the Oracle JDK.

The JavaFX version bundled with Java 7 was not completely open source so it could not be included in the OpenJDK (which is what you are using).

In you need to use Java 7 instead of Java 8, you could download the [Oracle JDK for Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and use that.  Then JavaFX will be included with Java 7. Due to the way Oracle configured Java 7, JavaFX won't be on the classpath.  If you use Java 7, you will need to [add it to your classpath and use appropriate JavaFX packaging tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-javafx-2-0-manually) to allow your users to run your application.  Some tools such as e(fx)clipse and NetBeans JavaFX project type will take care of classpath issues and packaging tasks for you.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, openjfx package places it in <JRE_HOME>/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar , exactly as described here.

Answer (score 7):

Mine were located here on Ubuntu 18.04 when I installed JavaFX using `apt install openjfx` (as noted already by @jewelsea above)

```
/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS seems to behave differently. Any clues?

Comment: I have installed openjfx, but I count not able to find usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar

Comment: I also have installed openjfx, but there is no jfxrt.jar anywhere. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu with OpenJDK, it installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`  (technically its a symlink to `/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`, but it is probably better to use the `default-java` link)

Answer (score 0):

The location of jfxrt.jar in JDK 1.8 (Windows) is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
```