# Linux (centos), openjdk 8, openjfx and netbeans 8

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, javafx, centos

So I installed at centos 6.4 openjdk 8, netbeans 8 and build openjfx. The only thing I can't uderstand is how to make netbeans work with built openjfx sdk. As openjdx sdk is in folder /temp while jdk is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8... I can't undertand how to add openjfx to netbeans as everywhere people say that jfx is already in jdk.

So, what now should I do to make all these work together?

Comment: @jewelsea I understand what you are talking about. But we need to use only open libs. That's why I have to do it with openjfx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest just to use the Oracle JDK if you can do that.  You could possibly hack something together by installing the Oracle JDK, seeing where in the JavaFX code is placed in the Oracle JDK and copying the OpenJFX build artifacts you created to similar locations in the OpenJDK, then pointing your NetBeans at the integrated OpenJDK/OpenJFX install.  Seems a lot of a work for a development environment though when you could just use Oracle JDK and it would just work out of the box.  You could always switch to OpenJDK/OpenJFX for final packaging for customer delivery once your development is completed.

Ubuntu has binary [OpenJFX packages available](https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openjfx.html), so if you could switch to Ubuntu, you should be able to use them (I've never tried it).

I am not aware that anybody has created anything similar for CentOS (this may change in the future).  If you stick with CentOS, you would probably need to follow my earlier advice of manually copying JavaFX files into the OpenJDK structure at the locations that NetBeans expects.  Usually the files you will need to worry about are the jfxrt.jar file (see [What's the location of the JavaFX runtime JAR file, jfxrt.jar, on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514310/whats-the-location-of-the-javafx-runtime-jar-file-jfxrt-jar-on-linux)) and the associated binary libraries (which must be in the correct location to be found), though there are possibly other files such as property files or javafx swt integration libraries that might be needed for correct function.

See related question:

- [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)