# Why doesn’t this textbook program recognise my Point2D objects?

Tags: java, class, object, compiler-errors

The following program is supplied in a textbook that I'm following. It should compute the distance between two coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) using the Point2D class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;

public class TestPoint2D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter point1's x-, y-coordinates");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter point2's x-, y coordinates");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();

        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(x1, y2);
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(x2, y2);
        System.out.println("p1 is " + p1.toString());
        System.out.println("p2 is " + p2.toString());
        System.out.println("The distance between p1 and p2 is " +
            p1.distance(p2));
    }
}
```

I have looked over it many, many times, and made sure it is correctly copied. When I try to compile the program in my terminal, I get the following error messages:

```
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
                      ^
TestPoint2D.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(x1, y2);
        ^
  symbol:   class Point2D
  location: class TestPoint2D
TestPoint2D.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(x1, y2);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Point2D
  location: class TestPoint2D
TestPoint2D.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(x2, y2);
        ^
  symbol:   class Point2D
  location: class TestPoint2D
TestPoint2D.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(x2, y2);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Point2D
  location: class TestPoint2D
5 errors
```

Why won't the program recognize the new Point2D objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is jar for JavaFX runtime jar, refer to this question here on SO 
[What's the location of the JavaFX runtime JAR file, jfxrt.jar, on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514310/whats-the-location-of-the-javafx-runtime-jar-file-jfxrt-jar-on-linux)

it provides a detailed explanation about the location of jfxrt.jar in Java 7 and 8.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Wow, I was completely unaware of this. Thank you very much!