# Package JavaFX does not exist (Windows 7 JDK 8)

Tags: windows, compilation, javafx, package, java-8

I'm attempting to get started using JavaFX, but when I try to compile [Hello World, JavaFX Style](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm), I get the error "package javafx does not exist". I uninstalled JDK (7) and JRE and installed JDK 8, which was suggested to help others with similar issues, however this did not help. Then I tried manually adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar" to the classpath environment variable . Despite all this, I still get the same error.

My classpath, in case it helps:
.;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;

Comment: How are you compiling your java program? Are you using an IDE ? Why does your classpath has `QTJava.zip` ?

Comment: I'm compiling via cmd with "javac gui.java". I'm not sure why QTJava.zip is there, but I did not add it :/

Comment: I guess these are your `PATH` entries in Environment Variables. Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/9436341/1759128

Comment: I'm using java 8, but typing javac gui.java does not work for me. Should I follow the instructions for java 7 instead? Otherwise that answer is not useful to me. Sorry I did not check the answer before I posted my original comment requesting you to mark as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile code using JavaFX 2.0 (using command line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-code-using-javafx-2-0-using-command-line)

Comment: Done ! Welcome to SO. Always search for questions before posting one in SO :)