# JavaFX packages not found

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a project with combined Swing and JavaFX components but JavaFX packages are not found by my IDE (tried with Netbeans and Eclipse).

```
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
```

says `package javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel does not exist`, same for any other fx packages.

This happens when I create project using `new project > java application`, but if I try to create JavaFX sample, it works...

I have no idea what am I missing here. Here are some background information and steps I have tried:

1. I am using win7 and jdk7 (in which java FX should be included)
2. My project in Netbeans (version 8) has JDK 1.7 selected as a deafult library
3. I updated my path: `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`
4. And also system Path: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\bin;C:\Dev\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar`

What else should I do to make JavaFX work? Thanks for any troubleshooting... All the information about setting JavaFX so far seem to be very outdated.

Comment: you need eclipse kepler to use javafx

Comment: @raj that's not true at all, at my work I use Juno. Plus this question is about Netbeans.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile code using JavaFX 2.0 (using command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-code-using-javafx-2-0-using-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include in the Project in your IDE the `jfxrt.jar` otherwise it will not be included as this was the default behavior prior to Java 8.

Then depending on your system and the way your build your jar for your project, and it also must be there for running the `jar`. So make your project also export the required libraries.