# Java8u40 Missing packages after import

Tags: javafx

I've recently imported one of my projects to another computer. It uses the same jdk(Java8u40) and IDE (Netbeans 8.0.2) as the previous machine. However, after I've imported the project, it appears that the TextFormatter class is missing. I'm not sure why it would be missing a single import from the same .jar file.

My imports:

```
    import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
```

Error Message:

```
     error: cannot find symbol import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
     symbol:   class TextFormatter
     location: package javafx.scene.control
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the output from `java -version`?  I'm assuming you've seen this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361270/javafx-packages-not-found

Comment: I suspect it is not really using JDK 8u40 (or later), but an ealier JDK 8 release.

Comment: What does the "Help->About" window say? Does the project use the correct platform (Project->Properties->Libraries)?

Comment: You were all correct. It was using the wrong version of Java8. Thank you very much for your help.