# Eclipse not running JavaFX application - runs 'java' application

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

Whenever I create a project in Eclipse and include javafx, the application does not load when I click the run button.

e.g.

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This should run a simple hello world application, taken from the oracle documentation. However when I 'run' this code, no windows open. Instead an application called 'java' opens. It appears 'java' is simply a 'unix executable file' located in 'jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/contents/home/bin'. The application 'java' displays absolutely nothing, and cannot be shut down without force quitting.

I'm running eclipse on a Macbook. I've probably left out some important details...

Does anyone know why my application is not running as it should? Forgive my naivety, I'm new to java and eclipse.

Many Thanks

EDIT:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFX extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
            launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

This simple program also gives the same error.

Comment: 'java' is the executable for the JVM, inside of which your Java/JavaFX application executes. You're showing the implementation of `start` but apparently calling a method named `launch`.

Comment: it's the code taken from the oracle website http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm 

is it incorrect?

Comment: No, the code is correct. @nitind this is the correct way to launch a JavaFX application. (The static `launch()` method is inherited from `Application`.) This runs fine for me (on Mac OS X 10.9.5).

Comment: so have you any idea what I am doing wrong? or is my eclipse set up incorrectly?

Comment: Try running from the Terminal? First check your Java version with `java -version` and then try `java -cp /path/to/project/bin test.test`. (`/path/to/project` should be something like `~/Documents/workspace/projectName` and the `bin` subdirectory should contain `test/test.class`. Folders etc may very depending on your Eclipse setup.)

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25" - Joes-MBP-2:~ JoeMorgan$ java cp ~/Documents/workspace/MenuTest/bin/test test.Application
Error: Could not find or load main class cp

Comment: to specify command line arguments to the java runtime, prefix them with a minus sign, for example `java -cp`.  However in your case you don't need to use a class path, instead change the current directory to ` ~/Documents/workspace/MenuTest/bin` and issue the command `java test.Application`.  For more info see: [Compile code using JavaFX 2.0 (using command line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436219/compile-code-using-javafx-2-0-using-command-line).  Also try this [e(fx)clipse tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1).

Comment: Joes-MBP-2:~ JoeMorgan$ cd ~/Documents/workspace/MenuTest/bin
Joes-MBP-2:bin JoeMorgan$ java test.Application
Error: Could not find or load main class test.Application

Comment: test.application does not exist in that bin folder, only test.class...

Comment: Since both your package name and your class name are "test", you should have a "test" directory containing "test.class". (Following the standard naming conventions - packages all lower case and class name beginning uppercase - will help here, however...) From the *parent* of the "test" *directory* (it should be `bin`), run `java test.test`.

Comment: I was using lowercase just to make a quick example. Joes-MBP-2:test JoeMorgan$ cd ~/Documents/workspace/MenuTest/bin/
Joes-MBP-2:bin JoeMorgan$ java test.test
Error: Could not find or load main class test.test

Comment: Inside `bin` is a `test` folder, and inside that is `test.class`?

Comment: okay it appears that the folder was incorrectly named. now when I run the command Joes-MBP-2:bin JoeMorgan$ java test.test the application loads as it should. So i guess i'm getting somewhere. However it does not run eclipse

Answer (score 16):

So I know this is an old question, but I ran into what I *believe* to be the same issue recently and wanted to share the solution I found (although I have no insight as to *why* it works).

[pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S7Ol.jpg)

Go to Run Configurations for the main class, and on the "Arguments" tab, uncheck the box where it says "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT".

To add a visual example of the problem so that someone more knowledgable than I can possibly explain why this happens/why this solution works:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec821.jpg) is what you get when you try to run the program. An application simply called "java" appears to be running, but nothing is showing.

I hope this information is able to help someone.

Comment: This is a great answer (+1), but a deeper explanation would be more helpful (if anyone more knowledgable can pitch in)

Answer (score 1):

possible solution install this from the eclipse marketplace https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

Comment: No, e(fx)clipse is not essential to run JavaFX application from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when I was trying to run JavaFX main class in an existing SWT project with maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When I comment out this dependency, application window was shown and everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, I created a new project in Eclipse for Java and copy / pasted your code into it.  Then just simply clicked on the run icon.  It worked perfectly.  I'm going to attach screen grabs of my setup for you.

[image: Initial Start up]

[image: Run configuration Main]

[image: Run configuration Arguments]

[image: Run configuration command line]

Answer (score 0):

if the pane is not showing up go to run configuration by clicking little arrow by run button and go to argument tab and uncheck the -use the -xstartonfirstthtread box then run again.