# GUI not showing up with JavaFX 15 using Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, user-interface, javafx

I've been following instructions to build a Hello World JavaFX application using Java JDK 15 and JavaFX 15. I've added a run configuration described here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse. When I run the program on my Mac I receive no errors in my console but the GUI does not appear. Building the same application on my Windows computer I am able to build and see the GUI.

Main.java

```
package hellofx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofx.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package hellofx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    public void initialize() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        label.setText("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + "\nRunning on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
    }
}
```

hellofx.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="hellofx.Controller">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution to this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846883/eclipse-not-running-javafx-application-runs-java-application).

> Go to Run Configurations for the main class, and on the "Arguments"
> tab, uncheck the box where it says "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread
> argument when launching with SWT".